# creating a database scheme for storing information about an item, which option is better?

Tags: database-design, schema

I have a database which stores information about various items. In particular, for each item I need to store the name, type and color. Each type can have a various amount of different colors. For example, I need to be able to ask 'what color can an item of type A have?'

I'm struggling to see how I should best structure my database. Each item has a color and a type, but I also need to capture the fact that each type has a unique range of colors available.

currently I have these ideas:

```
FIRST OPTION

items            (ID(PK), name, types_and_colors_ID (FK))
types and colors (ID(PK), type_name (FK), color(FK))
types            (ID(PK), type_name)
colors           (ID(PK), color_name)


SECOND OPTION

items            (ID(PK), name, type(FK), color(FK))
types and colors (type (PK FK), color (PK FK))
types            (ID(PK), type_name)
colors           (ID(PK), color_name)


THIRD OPTION

items            (ID(PK), name, type_color_id(FK))
types            (ID(PK), type_name))
type_colors      (type_color_id, color_name (PK), type_id (PK))
```

Comment: are the colors and types fixed, or will you be adding types and colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your option 2.

- I have added an ERD showing 2 possible solutions (underlined columns are PKs). They are both Normalized to 3rd+ Normal Form. The first answer is not OK, because type information -  the `TypeName` - appears in 2 tables. This is not following normalization rules.
- Note that in the first diagram, the Foreign Key from `Item` to `Item_TypeColor_Assn` is `(TypeID, ColorID)`, while in the second diagram, the FK is the `(SeqID)` which of course references the (surrogate) Primary Key `SeqID`.
  Also note that in both diagrams, there is **one** Foreign key (and not two as the text in image falsely implies). It just happens that in first diagram, the Foreign key is compound (composite).
- In both diagrams/solutions, there is an FK `(TypeID)` from `Item_TypeColor_Assn` to table `Type` and one FK `(ColorID)` to table `Color`. The two solutions are identical in that aspect.

Edit 2

To answer your comments:

If you need to change a color combination for an item, you must delete a row from ItemColor_Assn table and re-insert a new row with the desired combination.

I have also updated the diagram so that the FK on item is nullable and won't cause a cascade delete on item when that happens.
*(this is a decision you have to make, whether that FK column needs to be nullable or not and whether the deletes are to be cascaded. Just offering an option)*

As per your other suggestion, you can do that too, however, where would the color names come from, I mean the literal "Red" for example? If you want to have a color table containing the text and have the text repeated in the ASSN table, then this would be against normalization, however, is valid from the logical standpoint.

[image]

---

Unrelated to the design issue, here are my (@Emmad's) personal preferences for naming style:

- Use singular name for table names.

Explananion: use singular names because relationships are read per single occurence. So you'd say Each (item) has Color.

Comment: You have `TypeID(FK), ColorID(FK)` in table `Item`but you don't explain if that is one compound FK or two FKs (to `Item_TypeColor_Assn`)

Comment: When you create a FK constraint on a compound key, you get 2 separate keys appearing in the child. Yes they are separate keys representing 1 compound PK (not 2 separate FKs) because the parent table has the 2 keys as part of 1 Primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One question I have is what would happen in the following situation. Let's say two types have the same color, yellow. What If I later decided that I wanted to change the color of a type from yellow to dark yellow? It seems like it might be rather tricky

Comment: What if I instead moved the color_name to the item_TypeColor_Assn table

Comment: Still the phrase *"... so that you don't have **two FKs** in Item"* is confusing.

Comment: @ypercube, in the child, there are 2 physical columns in combination they represent THE KEY of the parent.

Comment: @Emmad: That (*" in the child, there are 2 physical columns in combination they represent THE KEY of the parent"*) is correct. So, add it in your answer! And remove that ***"2 FKs"*** (it's in the image text)

Comment: For the OP and the answerer: I've edited the answer as I felt it had some flaws. The comment/answer/edit/repeat procedure just takes too long when people live in different timezones.

Answer (score 3):

With the first version the schema design itself forbids having invalid type-color pairs, so I would choose that one.  With the second version you will need an extra mechanism (a trigger for example) to maintain valid state of the items.

From a querying point of view, it means one more `JOIN` on quite simple tables, I would not expect that causing performance or maintainability problems.

### **EDIT**

Well, I finally realized what could Emmad mean on *'The first answer is not OK, because type information appears in 2 tables'* - I silently considered `type_name` in your line

> types and colors (ID(PK), type_name (FK), color(FK))

a typo, and a foreign key on `types.ID` instead of name.  With this modification my suggestion is quite the same as Emmad's second diagram.